# How to have a fixed and % elements alongside one another in a line

Tags: css, layout, fixed

I want a container to be filled in a single line in the following way:

- 60px fixed yellow

And then of the remaining space:

- 20% blue
- 60% black
- 20% red

This is what I have so far (doesn't work):

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:100px;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #ccc;
}

.blue_container {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 20%;
    float:left;
}

.black_container {
    width:60%;
    float:left;
    background-color: black;
}

.red_container {
    width: 20%;
    float:left;
    background-color: red;

}

.fixed_conatiner {
    float:left;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 60px;
}

.transparent_container[type="fixed"] {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width: 60px;

}

.transparent_container[type="avazmishe"] {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="transparent_container" type="fixed">
        <div class="fixed_container"><br/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="transparent_container" type="resizable">
        <div class="blue_container"><br/></div>
        <div class="black_container"><br/></div>
        <div class="red_container"><br/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, all you have to do is subtract that fixed containers width from your fluid container with a left margin. Try this:

```
.transparent_container {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer Meysam:

http://jsfiddle.net/EcZ5j/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="transparent_container" type="fixed">
                <div class="fixed_conatiner">
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transparent_container transparent_container_2" type="resizable">
                <div class="blue_container">
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div class="black_container">
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div class="red_container">
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #ccc;
}

.blue_container {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
}

.black_container {
    width:60%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: black;

}

.red_container {
    width: 20%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;

}

.fixed_conatiner {
        float:left;
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 60px;
}

.transparent_container[type="fixed"] {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width: 60px;

}

.transparent_container_2{
    padding-left: 60px;
    word-spacing: -1em;
}

.transparent_container[type="avazmishe"] {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```